# How to send email notification to newly created user in Active Directory using ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, active-directory, smtpclient

I have implemented a web application which manage all the operations(User Creation, User modification, User termination) on Active directory(@server.local).

I want to send a email from **@server.local** domain when an user creation has done, we need to notify the manager of the user.

Now the problem is, I am not sure about the SMTP configuration settings on that  AD server and I have tried a method to send a mail. But It does not send the mail successfully. Its showing error message like **Failure sending mail.**

My Code is:

```
  string SMTPHost = "10.26.60.350";
  string fromAddress = "Admin.User@Server.local";
  string toAddress = "Test.User@Server.local";
  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage notMess = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
  notMess.To.Add(toAddress);
  notMess.Subject = subject;
  notMess.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddress);
  notMess.Body = bodyParams;
  System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SMTPHost);
  smtp.Send(notMess);  // Here I am getting the exception
```

How to resolve this propblem? Do we need to configure any settings on AD server to send mail by using @server.local domain? Please help me on this and suggest me about this.Thanks

Comment: 10.26.60.350 is not a valid IP address, typo?

Comment: Your question makes it sounds like the AD server is where the SMTP configuration settings are. This is only true if that server also happens to be your Exchange server (assuming that's your mail server software).

Comment: Are you running an email server at Server.Local?  SMTP sends messages to an email server.  I would recommend hMailServer if you aren't using one currently.

Comment: @DeanWard: 10.26.6.150, This is my AD server ip address.

Comment: @mason: In that server we have our active directory environment. We don't have exchange in our AD environment server. Then how possible to send mail from that server domain @server.local?

Comment: @JasonGeiger: we are not running any email server on Server.Local. We need to send mail from that server with the ip number 10.26.6.150 and domain name server.local.

Comment: Do you have **some mail server**, somewhere? You can't send email without a mail server. The IP address of the AD server doesn't matter.

Comment: @mason is correct; you need the IP address of an SMTP server that is allowed to relay mail for server.local

Comment: @mason: we don't have any seperate mail server. How do we make the AD server itself as a mail server. Please suggest me any reference link to make a server as mail server. I am not aware of these things.

Comment: I assume you have an email server somewhere for company email. If it's not hosted on premises, then make sure your provider has SMTP configured and search their documentation for how to use it. That's really out of scope for this though, we're not here to help you set up an email server.

Comment: @mason: I really didn't aware of all those things which you told me before thats why I asked you. I thought that is based on our IIS level settings thats why i asked you. do you our internet connection provider?

Comment: IIS is not an email server. IIS is a web server. You must have an email server in order to send email. I do not understand what you mean by "do you our internet connection provider?" That is not a valid sentence.

Comment: In you previous comment you have mentioned like "provider has SMTP configured". what is the meaning of provider?

Comment: Provider=company that is hosting your email. Examples: Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo etc.